# Question about binomial probability when computing $\mathbb{P} (XY=0)$.

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be two independent binomial random variables and $X ∼ $Bin$(3, 0.4)$ and $Y ∼$ Bin$(3, 0.4).$

> Compute $\mathbb{P}(XY=0$).

$\mathbb{P}(XY=0$) = $\mathbb{P}$({$X=0$}$\cup${$Y=0$}) By the inclusion exclusion principle.

$$=\mathbb{P}(X=0)+\mathbb{P}(Y=0)-\mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=0)$$

$$= 0.216+0.216-(0.216)^2$$
$$\approx 0.39$$

> 1) I don't understand $-\mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=0)$ if they are **independent?**
>
> 2) And why does it become $(0.216)^2$?

Comment: I noticed that you deleted this post just after you received an answer. **Don't do that.** It's unkind to those who took the time to answer your post and smells of foul play. It also deprives future visitors who have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

- $$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

holds regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are independent or not. This is inclusion-exclusion principle. Note that independent doesn't mean mutually exclusive.

- If $A$ and $B$ are independent, we have $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.